# ios/xcode/coredata: How to mimic ajax call in objective c

Tags: ios, core-data, tags, textfield

For a tag system, when entering a new item, I'd like the user to start typing a letter or two and see possible tags...similar to how SO tags work on the website i.e. Ajax.

Is there a way to do this on IOS?

Basically the Add Item screen has some empty text fields where you put the name etc.

I'd like to have an additional empty field where as you enter letters you see possible tags appear below and can then select one to tag the item.

The tags would be served from an entity or table so there would have to be a call to core data to supply them based on the letters typed.

Do I have to implement a full blown tableview to do this?  Or is there a way to make the possible tags show up below the textfield box.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a third party development in order to make what you want. In a recent project I have used this one:

https://github.com/EddyBorja/MLPAutoCompleteTextField

Comment: Looks promising.  Can you connect this to a core data request?  I want users to see list of tags placed by other users in entity.

Comment: You can do it by populating It's datasouce with a NSArray with data from your CoreData. You have to implement delegate methods and use as MLPAutoCompletionObject your NSManagedObject